# Using Modulo to calculate remainder

Tags: javascript, modulo

```
    //How much pizza each party goer will recieve
    const slices = 3; //Number of slices 8
    var people = 8; //Number of people 25
    var pizzas = 10; //Number of pizzas 10

   //pizzas ordered times the number of slices, divided by the number of people & asign         slicePerson variable
   var slicePerson = (slices * pizzas)/people;
  //print out how many pieces per person
  console.log("Each person ate" + " " + slicePerson + " " + "slices of pizza at the party.")



  //Sparky gets what remainder of pizza
  //Slices by pizzas used modulo to give remainder with people
  var dogFood = 30 % people;
  //print out how many slices sparky got
 console.log("Sparky got" + " " + dogFood + " " + "slices of pizza.");
```

the question:

At the pizza party Sparky, the host’s dog is excited, because he gets the leftover pizza after the slices have been divided up evenly among the guests. Assume guests get whole slices, how many whole slices will Sparky feast on?
Example data set: 10 people, 4 pizzas and 8 slices per pizza will mean each person eats 3 slices and Sparky gets 2 slices. (Note that this is an example, your code should work and give me the accurate results no matter what numbers I put in for those given variables.)
     Given:
Don’t make new given variables/constants for this. Instead use the givens you set up for Slice of Pie I.
     Result Variables:
Number of slices Sparky gets to eat.
    Result to Print:
“Sparky got X slices of pizza.”

I've plugged and tried as many methods as I could think of but I can get it to work with different numbers. It's always off by a tiny bit.

Comment: This question is very confusing, for example: const slices = 3; //Number of slices 8 : So is it 3 or 8 ??

Comment: Hint - first figure out how much Sparky gets, then figure out how much each person gets.

Comment: Looks like homework ;)

Comment: Allow me to introduce you to my friend [`Math.floor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor).

Comment: It is homework and its really confusing haha. I've figured out how much each person gets but not sure how to use the modulo "%" to extract the remainder for display in the console..

Comment: I was using different numbers for the equation thats why in the comments there are different numbers. the number don't matter, its the result i'm needing to be correct no matter what I plug in.

Comment: `var slicePerson = Math.floor((slices * pizzas) / people);` and `var dogFood = (pizzas * slices) % people)`

Answer (score 0):

```
var leftovers = (slicesPerPizza * numberOfPizzas) % numberOfGuests;
var slicesPerPerson = (slicesPerPizza * numberOfPizzas - leftovers) / numberOfGuests;
```

each guest gets slicesPerPerson, and Sparky gets the leftovers.